# How to play a sound clip once, even if the code should call it more than once?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm creating a **JavaScript** game, and want a splash clip to `sound` if the player falls in the water (and dies).

However, since the water is made up of multiple blue cubes, the audio currently repeats itself for every 'block' of water the player falls into.

Is there anyway to get the audio to only play once, regardless of how many water blocks the player touches?

I am trying to use a `for statement`, but no luck.

```
var count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var splash = new Audio("splash.mp3");
     if ( type == "water"){
          splash.play();
     };
};
```

Comment: Try my answer it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please first fix for loop error...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    var splash = new Audio("splash.mp3");
        if ( type == "water"){
            splash.play();
        };
};
```

And let us know if that solved your problem?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction! Unfortunately, the audio still plays multiple times, even when I correct that section.

Comment: No need of writing semicolon at the ending brace, `{`.

Comment: I'm sure that there is some other code that calls this sound to play again. Is there any other loop outside code block you provided? You could try with some global variable. For example set global var like: var soundPlayed = false; and then check `if ( type == "water" && soundPlayed === false){ //play sound }`

Comment: There isn't any loops in that section. I tried making the global variables as suggested, but it seems to freeze my game on contact with the water, and no audio is played.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to alter the Audio class, or alternatively you will have to keep track of when it stops playing so you can change your boolean.

So

```
if (!splash.isPlaying()) {
    splash.play();
}
```

Or

```
if (!splashPlaying) {
    splashPlaying = true;
    splash.play()
}
```

Comment: function isPlaying(audelem) { return !audelem.paused; }

Answer (score 0):

```
 function isPlaying(audelem) { return !audelem.paused; }

 var count = 1;
 var splash = new Audio("splash.mp3");
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){ 
      if ( type == "water"&&!isPlaying(splash )){
           splash.play();
           break;
      };
 };
```

or

```
 var count = 1;
 var splash = new Audio("splash.mp3");
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){ 
      if ( type == "water"&&audelem.paused){
           splash.play();
           break;
      };
 };
```

[referene](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp)